# Why doesnt this regex match this string in docker automated builds

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Can someone please help me understand why this Regex:

```
(^(?!(master|stage|develop)$).*)
```

Does not match this string:

```
SBSS-001-WilLTest
```

In the Branch selector, but it matches just fine in every other regex program I’ve tried:

https://regexr.com/4di8b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the regex matcher used doesn't support negative lookaheads (`?!`).

There is a thread here regarding the decision to not support lookaheads in the default Go regex engine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E

Comment: Can you find documentation on that on their site? I dug through and didnt see anything of the sort.