# Docker Hub builds branch regex match not master

Tags: build, regex-lookarounds, dockerhub

I am using Docker Hub auto builds to create images. My desired behavior is to tag all commits to `master` as `latest`, which is easy, and also tag all branches with the branch name as the tag.

I have the following build rules configuration:

```
------------------------------------------
|Build Rules|Source          |Docker Tag |
------------------------------------------
|Branch     |master          |latest     |
------------------------------------------
|Branch     |/^(?!master$).*/|{sourceref}|
------------------------------------------
```

The master branch builds fine, but other branches don't trigger a build. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the regex matcher used doesn't support negative lookaheads (?!).

There is a thread here regarding the decision to not support lookaheads in the default Go regex engine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E

Unfortunately I can't think of any workaround for this except to follow a convention where you use a common prefix like a `_`

The regex would be `<prefix>.*` so if you endup using `_` then it would be `_.*`

PS: Copy from [Why doesnt this regex match this string in docker automated builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030134/why-doesnt-this-regex-match-this-string-in-docker-automated-builds)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Do you know how this can be achieved without the negative lookahead?

Comment: probably use a convention that all other branches will start with `_` or some common prefix?

Comment: Not a great solution, but I can't think of another. Could you update your answer to include that or an actual solution Then I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks Tarun. I've accepted your answer. If possible, could you add the regex that would work with the suggested prefix?

Answer (score 0):

While the regex matcher does not support negative look aheads, you just have to be a little more verbose.  There's 1000 ways to skin a cat with regex, and as the old saying goes, *"If it can't be done in regex, it can't be done."*

```
/^([^m].....|.[^a]....|..[^s]...|...[^t]..|....[^e].|.....[^r]|.{0,5}|.{7,})$/
```

[image: regex tests]

You can play with the regex here: https://regexr.com/56v52